# Connect MySQL on my host computer to my CentOS7 virtual Machine

Tags: mysql, virtual-machine, ssms, virtualbox, centos7

I have CentOS Linux 7 on my virtual machine using VirtualBox. I have no GUI, it's just the Terminal. I have Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio on my host PC (Windows 10). I'm trying to connect it to my VM and I can't figure it out. I've looked at several different sources and I can't get it to connect. Can anyone offer any assistance?

Comment: SSMS (says Obvious Man) connects to SQL Server instances. What sort of DBMS software did you install on your VM? SQL Server for Linux? You didn't mention that. Please [edit] your question to clarify. Note: if you want to use SSMS to talk to MySQL, you need to rig an ODBC driver. That's generally a big pain in the neck to get right. You might want to use another client program like HeidiSQL.

Comment: SSMS is for SQL Server.  If you want to connect to MySQL, use other client tools.